# jQuery UI Dialog Will Not Close

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery, razor

Given the following script:

```
$(function () {
    $(".editLink").button();

    $('#editPersonDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'Edit Person',
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $("#update-message").html('');
                $("#updatePersonForm").submit();
            },
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    });

    $(".editLink").click(function () {
        var dialogDiv = $('#editPersonDialog');
        var linkObj = $(this);
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
            dialogDiv.html(data);
            //validation
            var $form = $("#updatePersonForm");
            // unbind existing validation
            $form.unbind();
            $form.data("validator", null);
            // check document for changes
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
            // re-add validation with changes
            $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
            // open dialog
            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });

        return false;
    });
});

function updateSuccess() {
    if ($("#update-message").html() == "True") {
        $('#editPersonDialog').dialog('close');
        $("#commonMessage").html("Update Complete");
        $("#commonMessage").delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(3000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
```

If I click the "X" button on the dialog the form closes fine.  If I click the "Close" button then it does not close.  I have verified that the code for the "Close" button is being called.

Both the "X" button and the "Close" button are both running the same statement:  '$(this).dialog('close');'.  Why would one work and the other not work?

As an aside the dialog will not open a second time unless I refresh the page.  I imagine that these 2 problems may be related.

I have found many people with similar problems and a number of different solutions that worked for them.  Unfortunately none of them worked for me.

Further Info:

The dialog displays a partial view in an Ajax form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Person", null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
    },
    new { @id = "updatePersonForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="update-message"  class="hiddenDiv"></div>
    <div class="blockGraygradient">
        @Html.Partial("_CreateEditCommon")
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedPerson.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedPerson.RowVersion)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedPerson.CreateTime)
    </div><p/>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the cause of both problems (the close button not working and being unable to show the dialog more than once without refreshing the page) was that I had included references to my script files in both my main page and the partial view being displayed by the dialog.  Once I removed the script references from the partial view the problems disappeared.

(As an aside this has now raised another problem to do with an Ajax update back onto the main page when the dialog is closed.  I think this is the reason that I put the scripts into the partial view in the first place).

Comment: I found that the approach provided in the attached article helped me to get the jQuery UI Dialog working well: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/jQuery-Modal-Dialogs.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this instead.

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```

We had exactly the same problem. In the end, every time you re-opened the dialog it was actually re-injecting the dialog markup into the DOM. Then, when you click close (for the second time) it only closes the first occurrence of the dialog, but not necessarily the one that's open. You can check this using a run-time DOM inspector like FireBug or Chrome's built-in developer tools.

Comment: I have already tried calling 'destroy' and 'remove' without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You have too much recursion. You don't need to subscribe to the `close` event of your jQuery dialog and invoke `$(this).dialog('close');` inside it. Simply comment this line or remove completely the `close` event subscription:

```
$('#editPersonDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 800,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Edit Person',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
            $("#update-message").html('');
            $("#updatePersonForm").submit();
        },
        "Close": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I had the same problem prior to subscribing to the close event.  I only subscribed to the close event to test if the call to 'close' would run there.